# Print ASCII-art formatted SETOF records from inside a PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would love to exploit the SQL output formatting of PostgreSQL *inside* my PL/pgSQL functions, but I'm starting to feel I have to give up the idea.

I have my PL/pgSQL function `query_result`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION query_result(
    this_query text
) RETURNS SETOF record AS  
$$
    BEGIN
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE this_query;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

..merrily returning a `SETOF` records from an input text query, and which I can use for my SQL scripting with dynamic queries:

```
mydb=# SELECT * FROM query_result('SELECT ' || :MYVAR || ' FROM Alice') AS t (id int);
 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
```

So my hope was to find a way to deliver this same nicely formatted output from *inside* a **PL/pgSQL** function instead, but `RAISE` does not support `SETOF` types, and there's no magic predefined cast from `SETOF` records to text (I know I could create my own `CAST`..)

If I create a dummy `print_result` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION print_result(
    this_query text
) RETURNS void AS 
$$
    BEGIN
      SELECT query_result(this_query);                                                                                                                                   
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

..I cannot print the formatted output:

```
mydb=# SELECT print_result('SELECT ' || :MYVAR || ' FROM Alice');
ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
...
```

Thanks for any suggestion (which preferably works with PostgreSQL 8.4).

Comment: Can you post the PL/PGSQL function as you have it so far? It should be perfectly doable to run an arbitrary query and return a set of results using that language, but I'm not clear exactly what roadblocks you're running into.

Comment: @Scott, thanks, I update the question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to do anything with your result set in `print_result` you'll have to loop over it. That'll look something like this -

Here `result_record` is defined as a `record` variable. For the sake of explanation, we'll also assume that you have a `formatted_results` variable that is defined as `text` and defaulted to a blank string to hold the formatted results.

```
FOR result_record IN SELECT * FROM query_result(this_query) AS t (id int) LOOP
    -- With all this, you can do something like this
    formatted_results := formatted_results ||','|| result_record.id;
END LOOP;

RETURN formatted_results;
```

So, if you change `print_results` to return text, declare the variables as I've described and add this in, your function will return a comma-separated list of all your results (with an extra comma at the end, I'm sure you can make use of PostgreSQL's [string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-string.html) to trim that).  I'm not sure this is exactly what you want, but this should give you a good idea about how to manipulate your result set.  You can get more information [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) about control structures, which should let you do pretty much whatever you want.

EDIT TO ANSWER THE REAL QUESTION:

The ability to format data tuples as readable text is a feature of the psql client, not the PostgreSQL server.  To make this feature available in the server would require extracting relevant code or modules from the psql utility and recompiling them as a database function. This seems possible (and it is also possible that someone has already done this), but I am not familiar enough with the process to provide a good description of how to do that.  Most likely, the best solution for formatting query results as text will be to make use of PostgreSQL's string formatting functions to implement the features you need for your application.

Comment: Thank you @Scott: I knew I could manually format the textual output, but I rather wanted to understand if there is a way to exploit the standard sort-of-ASCII-art formatting SQL function that is used to beautify the results from terminal calls.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I understand what you want now.  The postgres server does not do that formatting, it just returns the data. The "psql" client you are using formats the data it gets.  You would have to grab the source for the psql utility and find the code in there that does that, and then compile it as a function for the postgres server.  Doable, I'm sure, but I couldn't tell you the exact steps. It is probably easier to implement something with postgres's string functions to meet your needs.

Comment: I see.. thank you Scott. PS You might update your answer with this detail at some point!  I believe I'll sort it out by decomposing my function to smaller PL/pgSQL functions returning `SETOF` records, so that I don't have to cope with home-brewed beautifyings.